# How to filter a pandas DataFrame to show the largest value for a given column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have NBA data for every game played until January of 2023. I went ahead and combined all the points and now have it as this:

[I used the groupby function to sum up total PTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqb9G.png)

I wanted to filter the dataframe to show the most points scored by a player for a given season.
For example:

| Season | Name | Pts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Player 1 | 2938 |
| 2021 | Player 2 | 2111 |

```
most_points = nba_data.groupby(by=['Season', 'Name'])[['Pts']].sum()
most_points.sort_values(by='Pts', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Reset_index then sort by points and drop_duplicates by name.

Comment: @Scott `groupby.idxmax` should always be preferred, sorting is `O(n*logn)` while `groupby.idxmax` is `O(n)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`df.groupby().idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) in the below approach will produce your expected output

```py
most_pts = nba_data.loc[nba_data.groupby(['Season'])['Pts'].idxmax()]
print(most_pts)
```